# SQL Update Query - Reversing a reference

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL, so this isn't too complicated.

I have two tables, with currently no Foreign Key Constraint implemented:

```
 Table Foo
============
ID  |  BarID
------------
1   |  NULL
2   |  NULL
3   |  NULL
```

and

```
 Table Bar
============
ID  |  FooID
------------
101 |  1
102 |  2
103 |  3
```

As you can see, the Bar table rows know which Foos they relate to, but the Foo table rows do not know which Bars they relate to. **I want to switch this around, so I get:**

```
 Table Foo
============
ID  |  BarID
------------
1   |  101
2   |  102
3   |  103
```

I want a SQL query that will set te BarID on the Foo table. In pseudo code:

```
for each Foo in FooTable:
  Bar = select Bar from BarTable where Bar.FooID == Foo.ID
  set Foo.BarID = Bar.ID
  set Bar.FooID = NULL
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: If you're wondering why I want to do this - it's an intermediary step in massaging a messy DB structure into a better one, with proper Foreign Key Constraints. Adding the FK constraints will be the next step, but I need Foo to refer to Bar, and not the other way around.

Comment: I did not expect so many different ways to do this... Are some of them better practice that others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update foo set
BarID = (select ID from Bar where FooId = Foo.ID);
```

It seems you want to clear out references from Bar to Foo. If so, do this:

```
update Bar set FooID = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Foo SET BarId=(SELECT Id FROM BAR WHERE Fooid=foo.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Foo 
JOIN Bar ON Bar.FooID = Foo.ID
SET Foo.BarID = Bar.ID
```

This should do it

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE Foo
USING Bar
SET BarID=Bar.ID
WHERE Foo.ID = Bar.FooID;
```